# Example for sorted String-array in Spinner

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner

Hi I want to show alphabetical sorted array name="planets_array" in spinner.
I found some info about .sort collections and array list but nothing of let me to understand how it's working.
So please help me and show me on example.
I have in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Dein Ziel</item>
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>
```

And in Activity.java:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Sort planets arrays.**

```
String[] planetsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
List<String> planetsList = Arrays.asList(planetsArray);
Collections.sort(planetsList); //planetsArray will be sorted
```

**2. Pass sorted array list to the Adapter.**

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planetsList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: For me it  works properly and code is easy to understand. Thx

Answer (score 2):

you can directly use in your xml...........

```
<Spinner
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/namespinner"
           android:entries="@array/planets_array"
           android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

use this line in XML `android:entries="@array/planets_array"`......

**OR**

change this line..........

```
    String [] myArray=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
    Arrays.sort(myArray);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,myArray);
```

enjoy coding............

Comment: sorry I forget to add string-array should bee aphabetical sorted

Answer (score 1):

you need to sort the array manually

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String[] planets_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
Arrays.sort(planets_array);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, planets_array);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String arr[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);     
    Comparator<String> stringComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
                        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
                    }
                };
  Arrays.sort(arr,stringComparator);
```

So now got you got sorted array so you can use this in `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```